What is the subject, and why is the verb conjugated like so, in this sentence?
I was talking to someone from Panama, and they sent me this message:

Mi profesora se dio cuenta que mis compañeros habían escrito la fórmula en el tablero y nos acusaron de copia masiva.

They also added that the complete form is nos acusaron a todos. I asked someone from Mexico about this, to see if this perhaps was a dialectical thing, but they agreed with the Panamanian. Both the Mexican and the Panamanian mentioned this phrase:

Pagaron justos por pecadores

My confusion comes from these two beliefs:

The subject of acusar has to be mi profesora.
If the subject is indeed mi profesora, then the correct conjugation has to be acusó, and not acusaron, since the former is 3rd person singular, which mi profesora is as well.

So, how come this sentence is correct nonetheless? And what does this phrase have to do with it?

To be grammatically correct, the sentence needs "de" before "que": Mi profesora se dio cuenta DE que mis compañeros habían escrito la fórmula en el tablero y nos acusaron de copia masiva.

You're right, if the subject is "la profesora", it should be "acusó" instead of "acusaron".
But using "acusaron" is not incorrect because it means that they weren't accused by the teacher alone. They probably were accused by the teacher and the director, by the teacher and the head of the department, by the scholar authorities, ... That plural subject is not explicitly mentioned in the text because it's not relevant for understanding the situation or because it would be mentioned in following sentences.


1 The subject of acusar has to be mi profesora.


2 If the subject is indeed mi profesora, then the correct conjugation has to be
acusó, and not acusaron, since the former is 3rd person singular, which mi
profesora is as well.

Tienes razón, es así.
El uso de "nos" sugiere que no solo los compañeros que escribieron la fórmula fueron acusados, sino también el hablante y posiblemente otros estudiantes. "Copia masiva" implica que el incidente no fue aislado, sino que involucró a varios estudiantes colaborando en la acción deshonesta.

Jajaja leyendo hoy un artículo sobre anfibologías me acabo de dar cuenta de que la frase tiene dos posibles interpretaciones. Todo depende de qué cláusula se anide con cuál:
A) En una de ellas, (la profesora se dio cuenta de que mis compañeros se machetearon) Y, debido a ello, (nos acusaron de copia masiva). En este caso,se refiere a que los propios compañeros que hicieron trampa salieron a buscar cómplices ni bien los engancharon para que todos pasaran por el mismo castigo.
B) En otra posibilidad, podría ser que la profesora se dio cuenta de que (mis compañeros se machetearon y nos acusaron de copia masiva). En este caso, se refiere a que la profesora se dio cuenta de que quienes habían cometido la infracción no fueron todos como ella lo creía, sino sólo un grupo reducido del curso, que salió a acusar al resto.
Como bien es harto sabido ya, no es necesario mencionar al sujeto del verbo porque el verbo lleva la misma información del sujeto en la conjugación. Por lo tanto, ‘acusaron’ podría referir a un grupo de terceros cualquiera no necesariamente involucrado, como lo dice en la otra respuesta (o sea, es otra interpretación más de la frase), pero yo creo que se refiere a los compañeros.
